# C++Builder Community Edition

Tags: c++builder

I have installed the C++Builder Community Edition and I can only create Delphi projects not C++. Is/Are there any additional tool(s) should be installed?
Note: from Help>About I see :Installed update Delphi 10.2 and C++ Builder 10.2 Update 3

Comment: Are you sure you installed C++ Builder and not Delphi? This should not be happening.Installing C++Builder should not include anything (codewise) related to Delphi.

Comment: here is the link : https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/starter/free-download. I have tried it three times so far, and I always get a file named radstudio10_2_3_esd__93231.

Comment: @MedoMe: That is the same file downloaded for Delphi CE. I guess the license key should be different, so it installs only one of the two supported products. Did you try with a different license key (did you get a new one each time?). Note that I can't try this, because CE won't install if the full product is installed already.

Comment: I got 3 emails with same serial number

Comment: @ Rudy Velthuis : That's absolutely correct. During the installation I had to select NEW license key. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Community Edition offers Delphi and C++ Builder separately. There is no RAD Studio Community Edition that offers both.

Answer (score 0):

You might download delphi installation package rather than C++ builder community installation package.
Embarcadero didn't release combined installation package includes both programming languages.